# launching installed(like picasa,skype) app which are on my emulator home screen,from within my app(android)

Tags: android, android-intent, picasa

i want to launch picas app which i have downloaded on my emulator, from my application..
i googled a lot but  got only how to  upload  images on picasa..
i need to launch the whole stand alone application picasa from my application using some intents and/or some API's..

i want to know is this possible or not...if this is possible i can very well launch almost all downloaded applications from my application....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had asked that before: [how to launch picasa from my app(android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282870/how-to-launch-picasa-from-my-appandroid/4283060#4283060)

So again: get the `package name` of the app and launch it with the method described.

Comment: well you are right but my question is i got the package name, using that i am getting run time error...as you given the example for browser thats fine,how did you come to know about browser package,i mean to say how can i  find names of all available packages (including picasa package) in android...give me some web links..

Comment: How about this: http://www.eoeandroid.com/viewthread.php?tid=28132&from=recommend_f or this: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg44920.html

Comment: ok thx but in that code there are some following syntax error its showing....getInstalledApps(remove invalid modifiers),log(create method log),apps(remove invalid modifiers)..